# Find indices of multiple maximums in a vector

Tags: r

`which.max` Determines the location, i.e., index of the (first) minimum or
     maximum of a numeric vector. If the vector has multiple max, how can I retrieve all of them?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You could do `which( myVector == max(myVector) )`, which is basically what `which.max` is (except that `which.max` stops at the first occurence and is implemented a bit more efficiently).

Comment: You might consider including a tolerance if you are working with floating point calculations.