# Returning a vector of positions using which.max

Tags: r, cumsum

```
  x <- seq(1:100)
  y <- 30
```

If I want to determine the location at which cumulative sum of x > y

```
  which.max(cumsum(x) >= y)
  [1] 9 #
```

Instead, if y is a vector i.e. I want to return for each element of 
y, the position of x

```
  y <- c(30, 60, 80, 90)
  which.max(cumsum(x) >= y)
  [1] 9
```

Why is it not retuning a vector of positions?

Comment: Why not use a for loop here? `for( i in y) { which.max(cumsum >= i) }` and then update a list

Comment: I want to avoid loop but thanks for suggestion.

Comment: You may need to use sapply?

Comment: Have you examined what `cumsum(x) >= y` looks like?  Try it with a smaller example perhaps. That might help you understand what is going on.

Comment: Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378390/find-indices-of-multiple-maximums-in-a-vector] there is an answer stating that `which.max` stops after the first occurence. Not sure if you could do what you want without falling into apply functions. Moreover, checking what `which.max` does, it says explicitly: Determines the location, i.e., index of the (first) minimum or maximum of a numeric (or logical) vector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another vectorized idea is to use `max.col` with `outer`, i.e.

```
max.col(t(outer(cumsum(x), y, `>`)), 'first')
#[1]  8 11 13 13
```

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: because it is not vectorised in y and `which.max` doesn't return more than 1 value.

Long answer:

`which.max` only returns an integer of length 1 or 0. It works in your first case because you are only seeking a single value.

In addition, vector recycling takes place when you are comparing vectors of different lengths. Again, in the first case this is straightforward, as a length 1 vector will get recycled and match each element of the longer vector. However, when the smaller vector has multiple elements, you may end up with a mismatch of what you expect, eg:

```
c(1,1,1,1) >= 1
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
c(1,1,1,1) >= c(1,2)
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

What you need to is either loop over y, or use `findInterval`:

```
findInterval(y,cumsum(x))+1
[1]  8 11 13 13
```

You add 1 because `findInterval` gives you the position that your value is last equal to or greater than.

Answer (score 0):

Is this solution appropriate?

```
sapply(y, function(i) which.max(cumsum(x) >= i))
```